# Javascript variables cannot...?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, redirect, pathname

I'm working up to PREV/NEXT buttons that will get the current pathname, find it in an array, and increment its index to output a redirect or link, not sure if my terminology is correct. I have it pretty much figured out, but I ran into this one question which is bugging me. There's a simple answer no doubt invisible to noobs but I don't know how to research it more than what I already did. Not a big deal to my code, but why can't I use a variable in the 2nd example; why do I have to spell out the redirect statement?

Example One: This redirect works.

```
<button onclick="pp();">PREV1</button>

<script>
function pp() {
var qq = window.location.pathname;
if  (qq == '/F:/0-website/wwwtesting/javascript_variables_cannot.html') {
    window.location.pathname = '/F:/0-website/webpage.html';
}
};
</script>
```

Example Two: I don't need the conditional as used in the last example, but without it the redirect doesn't work. What's the difference to JS? All I changed was to remove the conditional, and the alert works but the redirect doesn't.

```
<button onclick="rr();">PREV2</button>

<script>
function rr() {
var yy = window.location.pathname;
yy = '/F:/0-website/webpage.html';
};
/*alert(yy);*/
</script>
```

Comment: The redirection works by modifying `window.location.pathname`. If you remove that line...

Comment: What if, some day, your site is deployed elsewhere than `F:/0-website` ? It can happen, you know :)

Comment: `yy` has no special meaning, so assigning a URL to it wont do anything ... why not use `window.location.pathname =` like you do the first time where it works!

Comment: You're simply assigning a value to a variable called `yy` twice in the second example, not altering `window.location.pathname`. JS variables are not pointer-based, if that were your expectation.

Comment: Thanks, I had failed to notice that in example 1, it is not qq that does the redirecting. Your comments were very helpful.